# AIS31 Software and Documentation

Tags: randomness, nist

I have learned that there are two main test suitcase for randomness ([reference](http://www.issihosts.com/haveged/ais31.html)):

1. AIS 31 - German Federal Office for Information Security (BSI)
2. SP 800-90B - U.S. National Institute for Standards and Technology (NIST)

I was able to run NIST tests on my data. I was wondering if there is any software (and documentation) available for AIS31. I was only able to find general information about it.

Answer (score 1):

See the page below

https://www.bsi.bund.de/DE/Themen/Kryptografie_Kryptotechnologie/Kryptografie/Zufallszahlengeneratoren/zufallszahlengeneratoren_node.html

I looked at it with the Google translator.

There are quite a few useful links there. If you want full blown code for tests, you'd probably need to write your own.

Related question:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89020/what-comprises-the-ais-31-standard-for-trngs

Comment: so there is no software, right? I looked at the website (it has English format too), I found some guidelines, not software. I am looking for a AIS31 setup similar to what NIST has.

Comment: yes, you need to write the code yourself, as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a java application you can download from the  BSI website: https://www.bsi.bund.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/DE/BSI/Zertifizierung/Interpretationen/AIS_31_testsuit_zip.zip

Comment: I'm excited, but you have to supply more info please. I can fire it up, but can't perform any tests. A technical translation of the instructions would help. And the error messages. And where's the source for `Tester.class`?

Comment: I can't comment on your answer so I put it here. You need to fill in "Breite in Bit". Unfortunately I'm not sure what the effect of that setting is, I only use '1' here.

Answer (score -1):

An important point of AIS31 is §2.4.5, Additional Statistical Tests.  They subsume all other randomness tests, specifically mentioning SP 800-90B. So you would have to implement the theoretical tests AIS31 mentions yourself.  Although §2.4.5 implies that you can simply run with other standardised tests. For that reason I wouldn't bother with an implementation.  But if you do bother, you can test your code against `/dev/urandom` output, or binary expansions of the irrational numbers like $\pi, e, \phi, \sqrt{2}$ etc.

It's worth mentioning that these are not really the two *main* test suites. Diehard and [Dieharder](https://webhome.phy.duke.edu/%7Ergb/General/dieharder.php) are also very common, depending on the size of the sample you can generate. <s>With hindsight, you find that AIS31 is very uncommon in the wild for not having been implemented in a standardised code base.</s>

There appears to be an implementation:-

[image: code]

But I don't know how to use it on Java 11 :-(

---

The direct link to an English version of the PDF document with the name "A proposal for: Functionality classes for random number generators, Version 2.0, 18 September 2011" can be found [here](https://www.bsi.bund.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/DE/BSI/Zertifizierung/Interpretationen/AIS_31_Functionality_classes_for_random_number_generators_e.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=1).